# The traversal of a BST

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree, traversal, tree-traversal

I need your help 
Is it possible to have a binary search tree which pre-order and in-order traversals  generate the same result ?

I've tried to take an example tree consisting of 7 nodes , and i labeled the nodes from a to g ..
this is my tree :

```
         a
    b          c 
 d     e    f     g
```

where a is the root , b and c are its children , d and e are b's childrens , and f and g are c's children

The pre-order traversal gives this result : `a   b   d   e   c   f   g`
The in-order traversal gives this result :  `d   b   e   a   f   c   g`

So in order to get the same result i need that a = d = e and f = c .. which is not possible since it is a BST ..

Could you just check if it was correct ? 
And if my idea about traversals is correct ?

Regards ,

Comment: Do you just need one example of a BST where they're the same? Off the bat I can think of two *very* simple trees where this is true.

Comment: @musical_coder  yess please

Comment: Any tree where all the values are the same...

Comment: Not going to give the exact answer away, but these trees have a very small amount of nodes. In fact, look up the smallest number of nodes a BST is allowed to have. Does that fit what you're looking for?

Comment: Okey i got your point :) thanks alot :) Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a tree with only right children(i.e. a list) you will have its preorder being equal to its inorder traversal.

Comment: btw can you please check if i've understood the idea of inorder and preorder traversals right ? i mean is my example true ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework, so I won't go into too much detail. But yes, it is possible to have a binary tree with identical pre- and in-order traversals. Consider how you might make one with two nodes. Then consider how you might make one with three.